# how to enable a href in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form, like this:

```
<form action="" method="get">

    <select>
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <option value="1">P1</option>
        <option value="2">P2</option>
        <option value="3">P3</option>
    </select>

    <a href="page6.html" onclick="return false;">New Page</a>   

</form>
```

and I want to enable the href only if the option value is not "-". 
Can you help me, please?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "enable"?  I guess you're going to want to start by looking into some JavaScript tutorials.  Specifically you want to have an `onchange` event handler for that `select`, and you want to modify that `a` in some way to "enable" it.

Comment: Oana better research your self some about jquery you can use and get it done in a min

Comment: Do you want a solution with jQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your code:

```js
checkSelect = function ()
{
    var mySelect = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    return mySelect.options[mySelect.selectedIndex].text !== "-";
}
```

```html
<form action="" method="get">
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <option value="1">P1</option>
        <option value="2">P2</option>
        <option value="3">P3</option>
    </select>
    <a href="page6.html" onclick="return checkSelect();">New Page</a>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! It's what I want :)

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to add an onChange event to the select, And then when the change function is called you can do a check to see whether you would like to change your page with this value, See code below for example

```
<form action="" method="get">
    <select onchange="getValue(this);">
        <option value="0">-</option>
        <option value="1">P1</option>
        <option value="2">P2</option>
        <option value="3">P3</option>
    </select>

</form>

<script>
    function onChange(sel){
        if(sel.value != "-"){
            document.location.href = newUrl;
        }

    }

</script>
```

Comment: It's also necessary to remove the "onclick" attribute or change its value

Comment: Aah yes apologies I must have missed that part, Well he has a few solutions now hopefully may help him in another situation

Answer (score 0):

It should look like this with the onChange event, +1 to david

```
<form action="" method="get">
                            <select id="sel" onchange="myFunction()">
                                    <option value="0">-</option>
                                    <option value="1">P1</option>
                                    <option value="2">P2</option>
                                    <option value="3">P3</option>
                            </select>
                <a  id="link">New Page</a>
```

then myFunction should look like this

```
if(document.getElementById("sel").value != "-"){
 document.getElementById("link").href = "your link here";
}
else{
 document.getElementById("link").href = "#";
```

}

Comment: Instead of changing the onclick to return true or false, I thought it would be better to remove the href, I don't see why you need a link you can't use.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code

```
$(function() {
  $("select").change(function() {
    if ($("select option:selected").val() != "0") {
      $("a").attr("onclick", "javascript:return true;")
    } else {
      $("a").attr("onclick", "javascript:return false;")
    }
  })
})
```

Here is JSFiddle [code](https://jsfiddle.net/mtechdev/ft36mh9b/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function changeHref() {
        console.log(this.value)
        if (this.value == 0) {
                document.getElementById("anc").href="";            
        } else {
            document.getElementById("anc").href="page6.html";
        }
    }
    
    var select = document.getElementById('sel');
    select.addEventListener('change', changeHref, false);
```

```html
    <form action="" method="get">
        <select id='sel'>
                <option value="0">-</option>
                <option value="1">P1</option>
                <option value="2">P2</option>
                <option value="3">P3</option>
        </select>
        <a id='anc' href="" onclick="return false;">New Page</a>
    </form>
```

Comment: This is not working :|  The new page is not displayed... although I choose option 0,1,2 or 3... Thanks for your answer